# How to turn a PHP script into a proxy server?

Tags: php, http, proxy

We all know that HTTP uses port 80, what if i put my server's ip and the port 80 in the browser's proxy setting, will the browser sends the HTTP requests to my index.php which will fetch the website from server side and return response headers and body?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have Apache or such listening on port 80,  your requests will be sent to the server on that port. You should probably enable mod_rewrite and redirect every incoming request into index.php, otherwise the server will look for the requested filename and return a 404. Then you should use cURL inside index.php and echo the raw results, headers included.

The performance of the whole thing may well be less than stellar, I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Apache, there's no point in using a PHP script as a proxy - Apache has a perfectly good proxy ([mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)) module already, which would also eliminate the overhead (and problems) of running everything through PHP.